# How add 14 days on end date

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-server

I have End Date column and I want to add 14 Days on it auto when created, can I do it by workflow? Can I do it via jQuery. If yes how? if no how I can do it?

Answer (score 5):

Add a calculated column of type date and use formula

```
=[ActualDateField] + 14
```